# How to unpack the base of a refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator, appliances, installation

How does one unpack the thick foam base of a Bosch refrigerator? It is sitting on a 4” thick foam slab. The goal is to get it down to floor level without damaging, and I only have one helper.

Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tip and swivel until you've "walked" it off the foam.

- Cut the lip of foam off the side nearest you.
- Tip it toward you (enlist help if necessary) toward the side where you cut the lip off.
- While it's leaning toward you, tip it onto the left corner as you pivot the right corner toward you a few inches to get it off the foam.
- Tip it onto the right corner (now sitting on the floor) as you pivot the left corner up, toward you, then down onto the floor.
- Have your helper pull the foam out of the way.
- Gently stand it back up.

Notes:

- It doesn't matter if you start with the left or right side, I picked one, you could pick the other.
- It's probably best to tip the fridge toward its back as this will prevent the doors from swinging open, possibly smashing fingers, possibly throwing you off balance as they move, potentially damaging the hinge as it hits its limit at speed, or at a very minimum being annoying and inconvenient.
- As noted in the comments, check your instructions on which way to tip your fridge. The manufacturer may have a recommendation based on mechanical/structural details that evade my logic. If you tip it too far, you will need to let it settle - details on that should be in your manual, as well. Don't forget - they probably had it tipped as it was hand trucked around the store, onto the delivery truck and into your house. (They could be you if you hauled it home yourself...)

Comment: If you tip it **significantly** you should not plug it in for several hours in order to let the compressor oil settle, just to be safe.

Comment: Check the fridge instructions. Mine (different brand) wanted only to be tipped side to side, *not* front to back when being moved. I inferred that this was a structural concern, probably.

Comment: Both excellent points!

Comment: The mechanical/structural details may be about not draining oil out of the compressor into coils or whatever.  As when you lay a fridge on its side, you need to let it sit 12-24hr for the oil to go back where it belongs before you start it.

Comment: I got it off by cutting the lip of styrofoam on one side, tipping on the same side and sliding it on that edge down. Then, once one side was down, tool the bottom foam out. Also, there is no way this fridge was ever on it’s side. It was shipped direct from manufacturer or distribution center on a manufacturer’s pallet tied with straps standing up. Regardless, I ended up having it sit for a few hours as I was busy with something else. Installed and running with ease. Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Tilt it to one side about 30 to 40 degrees and have a coworker break or cut the foam off as far under the refrig as possible. Then tilt it in the opposite direction and remove the remaining piece.

Comment: Reminding me of an event in a Breaking Bad episode...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica ATM? :)